# Rails Deploy using Elastic Beanstalk - Can't convert array into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to perform a deploy a rails app on EC2 using ElasticBeanstalk, but I'm having some troubles. I was able to perform every step needed on my computer following Amazon's tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html).
After deploying the app, I keep receiving this error passenger error on my server: 
[image: Passenger error]

At first I tough this could be somewhat related to my config.yml file, so, here is how it is now:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%=['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME']%>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Any ideas on why could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password looks a lot like an array to me.  I think you might want `password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>`

Comment: I'm ashamed of my own Stupidity. Thanks Tom!

Comment: A second set of eyes always helps.